# Postgresql RULE order

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, rules

**What is the order that RULEs fire when applied to an INSERT?**

Are they done AFTER or BEFORE the record is inserted.

What I am trying to do is create a new record in another table, which will link to the record that was INSERTed.

Take for example; To make a rule that will creating a new page, when a document is created, so that a document will always start with an empty page record.

I have looked high and low, and maybe I'm asking Google the wrong question, but I cannot find any documentation about the order of execution for RULES.

Answer (score 0):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html)

> Multiple rules on the same table and same event type are applied in alphabetical name order.

So the ordering does not depend on the type of the rule, only on the name.

And it also explains how the rule is "applied"

> It is important to realize that a rule is really a command transformation mechanism, or command macro. **The transformation happens before the execution of the command starts**.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So the rule doesn't happen "before" or "after" a statement runs - it runs *instead* of that statement.

---

> *What I am trying to do is create a new record in another table, which will link to the record that was INSERTed.*

You definitely want an AFTER INSERT **trigger** for that. Forget about rules.

Which is also what the manuals recommends:

> If you actually want an operation that fires independently for each physical row, you probably want to use a trigger, not a rule

Comment: Hmm, but what about `ALSO` rules... these are run in "in addition to the original command", so there should be an order, shouldn't it?